# After creating a union of two tables in SQL, how to show sum from each table in a single line within SSRS Tablix

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to create a tablix in SSRS where a single row shows the SUM of work quantities for the TypeOfWork, from two separate database tables.

I created a dataset with a Union (sql shown is simplified, but is the basic idea) that allowed me to have sums of each type of work within each table--by way of how I did the grouping.  I can show the two sums, for each type of work, from the two tables in their own line on the SSRS Tablix, easily.  Such as:

Work Area | Type of Work | New Table Sum

Work Area | Type of Work | Old Table Sum

...and repeat

But how to show the sums in a single line, as such:

Work Area | Type of Work | New Table Sum | Old Table Sum

Here's the basic SQL:

```
SELECT SourceTable, WorkArea, TypeOfWork, Sum(WorkAmount)  
FROM 

(
SELECT 'OldTable' AS SourceTable, o.*
FROM Old o

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'NewTable' AS SourceTable
, NEWID()
, '2A077AC6-8040-49CB-B1FD-CD96D0A30533' AS [OldGuid]
, n.*

FROM New n

) AS ReportTable

GROUP BY WorkArea, TypeOfWork, SourceTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in your top query:

```
SELECT WorkArea
    , TypeOfWork
    , OldTableSum = SUM(CASE WHEN ReportTable.SourceTable = 'OldTable' THEN WorkAmount ELSE 0 END)  
    , NewTableSum = SUM(CASE WHEN ReportTable.SourceTable = 'NewTable' THEN WorkAmount ELSE 0 END)  
FROM 

(
SELECT 'OldTable' AS SourceTable, o.*
FROM Old o

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'NewTable' AS SourceTable
    , NEWID()
    , '2A077AC6-8040-49CB-B1FD-CD96D0A30533' AS [OldGuid]
    , n.*
FROM New n

) AS ReportTable

GROUP BY WorkArea, TypeOfWork
```

Comment: Fox. The results were similar, but your CASE allowed me to have a convenient way to name each of the totals.  I'm still getting separate rows for the sums for each table.  I tried grouping on TypeOfWork in the Tablix row group, but then it only showed the sums from the Old Table and did not show both sums.  I would have thought grouping on Type of Work would do it, but sadly I just takes the Old table info.

Comment: My bad, you need to remove the GROUP BY SourceTable - I fixed my query above.

Comment: when I try in SQL Server Management Studio, I get this error: Column 'ReportTable.SourceTable' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I removed SourceTable from the select clause, and it may be working...I'll test some more

Comment: BTW, you should remove SourceTable from your select statement for the record.